# Mapping from 'character' to 'double' in R

Tags: r

This is a fairly simple question but I have failed to find a great solution thus far.

I have a 'character' array as follows:

```
sample_names
```

which returns something like

```
[1] "A"     "B"     "C"
```

I want to use a particular element of `sample_names` to get another value in a different list. The other list may look like as follows:

```
sample_name_list = list(
"A" = "Apple",
"B" = "Banana",
"C" = "Coconut")
```

I want to go through the character array (`sample_names`) and replace each element with the corresponding value from `sample_name_list`. In the end, I would want a character array that reads:

```
"Apple"     "Banana"     "Coconut"
```

What is the simplest means of achieving this end? I have tried iterating through each part of the `sample_names` character array and trying to index into the list using `$` but it looks like that requires a `double` (rather than the `character` found in `sample_names`) for proper indexing.

Comment: Try `unlist(sample_name_list[sample_names])` or `unlist(sample_name_list)[sample_names]`

Comment: @akrun, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker The question title about converting to `double` is not clear to me

Comment: Sorry; I don't really know how to properly phrase the question. When I do the `unlist` function you told me about, I seem to receive `NULL`. Would you mind explaining the `unlist` function?

Comment: @xfrostyy if the input data list is as you showed, it is returning a named vector with `unlist` and I assume `sample_names <- c("A", "B", "C", "A")`

Comment: I guess a better question would be: how could I access the 'long' name from the `sample_name_list` given that my input (e.g. `A`) is a character? The `A` in `sample_name_list` is not a character.

Comment: @xfrostyy Both the solutions I posted should work given that inputs are named list and another a vector.  When you do `sample_name_list[c('A', 'B')]`, it returns the subset of list based on those names, then `unlist` to convert the list to vector

Comment: `The A in sample_name_list is not a character`.  that is not true because you can check `is.character(names(sample_name_list))`

Comment: @akrun's solutions both work for me with the data given in your example.  Can you please post a **reproducible** example, i.e. a data set for which @akrun's example does **not** work?  The `dput()` function may be useful to help us discover if there's something unusual about your input.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? 1) Why the title is `Mapping from 'character' to 'double' in R` when there is no double anywhere in the example shared ? 2) According to your post you have `sample_names <- c('A', 'B', 'C')` so doing `unlist(sample_name_list[sample_names], use.names = FALSE)` returns `#[1] "Apple"   "Banana"  "Coconut"` which is your expected output then why do you say it returns `NULL` ? 3) If it returns `NULL` it means you maybe have a different data structure or maybe need a better example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @RonakShah the use.names parameter is exactly what I would need! I can combine it with the response below from Akindele Davies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by creating a dataframe to serve as a lookup table and using the `match()` function.

```
foo <- data.frame(key = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  value = c("Apple", "Banana", "Coconut"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test <- c("B", "B", "C")
foo$value[match(test, foo$key)]
```

Comment: I like this solution but the issue is: how can I get the latter part of `sample_name_list` to be a plain list? I can get the `key` part by using `as.list(sample_names)` but do not know how I can convert to easily get the `value` that you have in your `foo`. This would be similar to getting the 'values' of a Python dictionary but I have been unable to do so without getting another list that does not play well with this proposed solution.

Comment: If `sample_name_list` is a named list, you can get the "keys" with `names(sample_name_list)` and the "values" with `sample_name_list`. Then you can convert an input vector with `sample_name_list[match(input, names(sample_name_list))]`.

Comment: I need both the 'keys' and 'values' as character vectors. I already have a 'key' character vector in `sample_names` but need to get the 'values' into their own 'character vector.' I can get the entire list as a character vector with `unlist(sample_name_lst)` but this character vector contains *both* the keys and values from `sample_name_lst`. How could I eliminate the `keys` from the resultant list?

Comment: NOTE: To my last comment, using `unlist(sample_name_list, use.names=FALSE)` enabled me to get the 'values' alone.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (though more verbose):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

sample_name_list <- sample_name_list %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  dplyr::rename("index" = 1, "name" = 2)

df <- sample_names %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::rename(index = 1) %>%
  left_join(sample_name_list, by = "index") %>%
  dplyr::select(name) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.vector()
```

Output

```
[1] "Apple"   "Banana"  "Coconut"
```